# No actualizar un campo updateOrCreate Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Estoy utilizando el metodo updateOrCreate de laravel y para un caso necesito insertar un valor si no existe.

```
$newproduct = PendingDocument::updateOrCreate(
 ['docentry' => $docentry],
 ['documento' => $documento,
 'cardname' => $cardname,                                
 'doctotal' => $doctotal,                                
 'totaldeuda' => $doctotal,
 'tipodecobro' => 'Vencimiento en 30 días',
 'deleted' => "ACTUALIZADO",
 ]
);
```

Para este caso necesito insertar un valor cuando no existe el registro, e insertar en el `tipocobro` el valor `vencimiento en 30 dias` ahora si existe este docentry en mi base de datos no inserte nada, se salte este campo, como debo cambiar mi codigo para esto? es posible poner una condicional aqui? de ser asi como seria el codigo? he probado con un if asi

`if('tipodecobro' == null){'tipodecobro' => 'Vencimiento en 30 días'},`  pero esto me da error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas tratando de crear un if dentro de un array? porque no haces primero el if y luego según el resultado das una respuesta para el campo que deseas insertar

Comment: Estás mezclando todo... esa sintaxis no es válida en PHP. Como mucho podés usar un [operador ternario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) Y [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) si encuentra los datos del primer argumento, hace un update con el segundo array. Si no encuentra registros en la db, crea uno nuevo combinando ambos arrays (primer y segundo argumento)

Comment: Cristian eso lo entiendo, mi pregunta es como harias un if para un campo! no como trabaja el updateOrCreate, eso se entiende amigo, habia pensado en un if ternario pero o lo hice mal o no me funciona tampoco ahi, gracias por el tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que debes hacer es un condicional de una sola linea con el codigo que tienes arriba te debe de quedar algo asi:

```
$newproduct = PendingDocument::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'docentry' => $docentry
        ],
        [
            'documento' => $documento,
            'cardname' => $cardname,
            'doctotal' => $doctotal,
            'totaldeuda' => $doctotal,
            'tipodecobro' => $docentry ? null : 'Vencimiento en 30 días',
            'deleted' => "ACTUALIZADO",
        ]
    );
```

esto lo que hace es validar (con un if de una sola linea) si la variable $docentry es `null` el campo tendra `Vencimiento en 30 días` si no el campo quedara `null`

Espero haberte ayudado saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, marcare tu respuesta como correcta, en realidad tome otra opcion donde consumire menos tiempo y a su vez menos recursos tambien, basicamente lo que hice mejor fue insertar el valor por default solo al crear el registro, ya luego pueden modificarlo o solo dejarlo asi tal cual. Gracias por el tip amigo, me ayudas a entender un poco mas como utilizar el ternario tambien! Saludos